# C shell doesn't work properly

Tags: script, csh

I tried csh in my Raspberry Pi model B today. I tried to run my program which includes `if` loops and the shell doesn't accept `endif`; however, when I use `fi` the program runs and operators like # and @ doesn't work.  Other problem is I can't run some of the commands that I run in bash like `adduser`, is that because of the c-shell; or any error in my system; or can it be because of my `ssh` connection?

Even this doesn't work:

```
if (0 == 0) then  
    echo "raspberry"  
else   
    echo "pi"
endif
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: There should be no differences from the PC-version of it. Can you prepare a small example script with the concepts that are not working and edit your question to contain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would probably be better as a comment, but I don't have the reputation.

Note that I am running ArchLinux, not Raspbian, so some of the paths might need adjusting in what follows.

The fact that "endif" doesn't work, but "fi" does suggests that you are not running your script under csh. bash or sh seem more likely.

If your script has a hashbang line at the beginning, check that you are calling up csh or tcsh and not sh or bash. It should look something like

```
#!/bin/csh
```

Alternatively, call up csh manually in the command console, and then try running your script

```
$> csh
$> ./your.script.name
```

You might need to use tcsh instead of csh depending on which is installed.

Finally, you can change your default shell with the usermod command

```
$> sudo usermod --shell /bin/csh yourloginname
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i already done it in csh command console i ll try reinstall.